# jquery selection attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Let's say I have a sample table like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/65BkH/

Now what i want is, if there is this `<button id="invite">Invite</button>`. I want this button to select the "invite url" of the selected contact. If you see the jsfiddle, if you click the checkbox, it will crop all the others contacts. How could i do that?

I've tried to target the contact, but i can only get the top contact.

```
$('#linkedin_match tbody .match .m a').attr('href');
```

what i want is to target the **currently** selected.

FURTHER PROBLEM :

This button I'm talking about is not the table per say.

```
$('#btn_save').click(function(e) {
        var hrefVar = $('#linkedin_match tbody .match .m').find('a').attr('href');
        alert(hrefVar);
});
```

Now if i used that, it still searches for the first link, even though i've selected the others. So, any changes?.

Comment: You are posting linkedIn urls of real profiles... :)

Comment: But its a PUBLIC WEBSITE, Is there a problem?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$('#invite').on('click',function(){   
    var url = $this.closest('tr').find('a').prop('href');
});
```

To get all the checked `href` related with the checked inputs in a array use this:

```
$('#invite').on('click', function () {
    var all_url = [];
    $('input:checked').each(function () {
        var url = $(this).closest('tr').find(' td.m a').prop('href');
        all_url.push(url);
    });
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Fwq54/2/)**

Comment: Thanks! Yes those are real people, and it's linkedin, it's a public website so no harm in posting. =)

Comment: Uhm sir ok, i need further help. This button i'm talking about is not on the table.

Comment: sir i've tried your's but mine is not the same in the demo, it grabs all the arrays not just one. its output is.

[undefined, undefined, "http://....", undefined]

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos, do you have a live link? otherwise the demo works as you want isn't it?

Comment: Ok i've got it to work by putting all_url[all_url.length-1]. BUT. we are getting the wrong url, i want to get the url in the "invite" anchor :)

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos, ok, the you need `var url = $(this).closest('tr').find(' td.m a').prop('href');`

Comment: @ArmanJonVillalobos, updated demo also to get the invite links href.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I will improve on this. Do you have a suggestion what book to read more on javascript? also logic? =)

Comment: Not all people are like you =)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.m').click(function(e){

  var hrefVar = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    alert(hrefVar);
  });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/67WSh/)